# Count Line Breaks?

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I am trying to count the number of lines in the `BillingAddress` field. I am familiar with the following methodology to count the number of times a substring occurs via formula:

```
LEN(TextField__c) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TextField__c, "substring", "")
```

Cool, should be pretty straightforward to use that, right? Just replace `"substring"` with a newline character, add `1` to the result, and you're done. Wrong.

Here is a list of values I tried to use in place of `"substring"`:

- `"\n"`
- `"\\n"`
- `"\r\n"`
- `BR()`
- `$Label.LineBreak`

  - `\n`
  - `\\n`
  - `\r\n`
- `SUBSTITUTE($Label.LineBreak, "-", "")`

  - `-\n-`

None of the above has worked. Some explanation on the `$Label` options is in order here. In searching for a solution, I found [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqBQAA0) which contains a particular suggestion by **Jesper Kristensen** people found helpful.

> Instead I ended up making this formula code, which gives me a plain line break.
>
> ```
> SUBSTITUTE($Label.LineBreak, "-", "")
> ```
>
> You also need to create a Custom Label named LineBreak, which contains two dashes separated by a line break.
>
> This code can also be used to remove line breaks:
>
> ```
> SUBSTITUTE(Street,SUBSTITUTE($Label.LineBreak, "-", ""),"")
> ```

**Additional Testing**

I tried changing the formula to `LEN($Label.LineBreak)`, and it outputs `2` with `\n`, or `4` with `-\n-`. So the issue does not seem to be caused by the length of newline characters calculating as `0`. I also tried setting `$Label.LineBreak` to `\n` and using `IF(CONTAINS(BillingStreet, $Label.LineBreak), 1, 0)`, and got back `0`. Using the `-\n-` approach yielded the same result.

**It is pretty obvious how to achieve this functionality using `Apex`, but I want a config only solution. It seems like it should be achievable.**

Comment: odd `LEN($Label.LineBreak)=4` for me. Did you mean `LEN(SUBSTITUTE($Label.LineBreak,'-',''))=2` ?

Comment: It would seem that RegEx would be another option to utilize for this as well since you could find the `\n` and even replace it using a RegEx function or simply retrieve the number of instances returned (not certain on the latter in a formula though, would need to go look at the docs). Not that I think it would be "better", faster or preferable to any other method.

Comment: @crmprogdev Good idea, but `REGEX(BillingStreet, ".+\n.+\n.+")` didn't work in a `Validation Rule`...

Comment: @AdrianLarson  In Apex you would need to escape the backslash. Don't know if that would apply to a validation rule or not.

Comment: I tried that also. Doesn't change a thing. @crmprogdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have an actual new line in the Custom Label. It will not work if you enter `\n`

**This will work:**

[image]

**This will NOT work:**

[image]

Comment: Wow. I don't know what else to say. Just wow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this directly in a Salesforce Flow.
Create a text template variable of type plain text.
In the example it is called "text_T_baseForCRLF"
[image]
In the text template write the following:

```
-
-
```

Then create a formula with name e.g. name "form_T_CRLF" and with content:
[image]

```
SUBSTITUTE({!text_T_baseForCRLF}, "-", "")
```

Then you can use it in the flow.

In my case i needed to split a question and answer string inside a loop. So i  came opp with this formula to get the question part. Then there is another formula to get the answer after the line shift.

```
TRIM(
   MID({!LOOP_overAnswerGroups}, 
   FIND("Q.", {!LOOP_overAnswerGroups})+2, 
   FIND(form_T_CRLF, {!LOOP_overAnswerGroups})-4
   )
)
```